# Is it possible to detect that the user will turn off the Bluetooth on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, detection

In my android app, the user has the possibility to do a firmware update via bluetooth of another device with his android phone.

My question is : Is it possible to detect when the user try to turn off the bluetooth and to send him a warning message like :"Warning turning off the bluetooth will interupt the firmware update !"

With the BluetoothAdapter Broadcast Action :

> public static final String ACTION_STATE_CHANGED
>
> Since: API Level 5 Broadcast Action: The state of the local Bluetooth
>   adapter has been changed. For example, Bluetooth has been turned on or
>   off. Always contains the extra fields EXTRA_STATE and
>   EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE containing the new and old states
>   respectively. Requires BLUETOOTH to receive.
>   Constant Value: "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"

It's only possible to receive a broadcast once the Bluetooth is already turned off (so it's too late for the warning ^^ )

Any help would be appreciate !
Best regards

Comment: You can't predict whether the user will switch off Bluetooth. It's up to the user. Yet I don't know for certain which Intent (if any) is broadcasted when the command is given though... I've worked with Bluetooth for a limited time, so I don't know it all, sorry.

Comment: The goal is to send a message to the user when he taps the "turning off bluetooth" button not before (so it's not prediction). But I'm not sure that it's possible to block the turning off command and send him a warning message instead...

Comment: It is possible if you know what Intent is being broadcasted through the system when the button is tapped. You can then register a receiver for that specific Intent, and do your warning there.

Comment: @ThaMe90: Yes, but even if we manage to get the broadcast and all, turning off operation will not be waiting for our approval. It will be turned off. So no use if we cannot stop/block the operation. Better to show a "firmware update failed" message on receiving the broadcast.

Comment: OK, but the bluetooth will still shuts down... That's my problem... And are you sure that we can register to this kind of Intent ? I only found the BluetoothAdapter intent ACTION_STATE_CHANGED which is sent once the bluetooth is already turned off. EDIT : userSeven7s was faster than me =P

Comment: I've checked for the Intents, and there isn't one that get's send when the button is pressed. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show such critical messages at the start of the firmware update. After that if the user switches off the bluetooth then its his responsibility. He cannot blame your software for any loss.
And I dont think we are allowed to block operations such as turning off bluetooth. Allowing such blocking will make it open to hacks. A malicious app could stop the user from switching off his bluetooth.

Comment: There is a warning message at the start of the firmware update, but if the user turn off the bluetooth anyway, the device will be blocked in a "firmware update" status and will be no longer usable for our customer. I agree that its his responsability but then the customer will have to send us his device and we will have to complete the update manually... That mean more job for us and fees for our customer. So I try to find a solution to avoid this.

Comment: I dont think we are allowed to block such operations. Allowing such blocking will make it open to hacks. A malicious app could stop the user from switching off his bluetooth.

Comment: It makes sense. So I think my only option is to sent a failed message and to restart the firmware update from the beggining... Thanks!